# How to Delete Multiple Rows With Checkboxes In Angular 11

Tags: angular, primeng, angular11

How to delete selected rows and how to delete all rows in angular 11?

this is my model

```
//model 
export interface Book {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;
}
```

This is my html file

```
//html
<p-table [value]="books" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="lazyLoadHandler($event)" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [loading]="loading" >
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th  style="width: 3rem" >
                        <nb-checkbox ></nb-checkbox>
                    </th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="id">Id <p-sortIcon field="id"></p-sortIcon>
                    </th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="title">Title <p-sortIcon field="title"></p-sortIcon>
              
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                      
                        <nb-checkbox value="books" #{{data.id}}></nb-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.title}}</td>
                    
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things to consider when removing selected items from a table and there are a lot of ways to implement that.

**One options is**:

1. Add a property `selected` in the interface
2. Create a checkbox for each item on the table with a two way binding on the property.
3. Create a button to handle the click event
4. Filter the array with the new values.

**Another option** is to keep the selected items in another list.
So when the button clicked you can filter the items dependently. For example:

```
onRemoveSelectedClicked() {
    this.items = this.items.filter(x => 
      this.selectedItems.every(y => y.id !== x.id)
    )
}
```

I created a small demo, using `primeNg`'s  table.

You can play around [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-tykcif?file=src/app/app.component.html).

*PS: I don't know how `nb-checkbox` works, but If you can't understand how it works from the documentation or it makes you more troubles than it should, then you should consider to replace it.
I would suggest you to use either **a custom checkbox with pure HTML and CSS** (like the example) or **`primeNg`'s [checkbox](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/checkbox)** or the **`primeNg`'s [selection mode](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/selection)** on the table.*

Comment: Can I do this without creating  property selected in the interface. [In this PrimeNg's demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablecrud-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct.ts) , they did not create. Is creating property in model is must ? or can i do another way

Comment: I updated my answer, as I mentioned there are a lot of ways.

Comment: If you found that helpful, don't forget to up-vote, If it solved your problem, mark it as accepted answer as well. Hope that helped